# How to conditionally set column to editable in kendo grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Right now I am setting the entire grid to false for editing

```
(function(){
    let grid = $('#MyGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    grid.setOptions({
        editable: false
    });
})();
```

The problem I now have is that I need to be able to allow editing on two columns and am not sure how to do that?

So if my columns are Last, First, Age, Gender, I need to allow editing in Last and First while the rest are not allowed to edit.

**EDIT**

This is needed for when I set the grid as "read only", but some of the columns need to still be editable

Comment: DId you check https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.editable? Switching back and forth from editable to non-editable can be done with https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.editable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control editability of columns through the data source model:

Leave the grid as editable, and turn off/on the field editable as desired.

Example (untested):

```
// make all fields uneditable (protected)
$.each(grid.dataSource.model.fields, function (name, options) {
  options.editable = false;
});

// unprotect the two fields in which changes will be allowed
grid.dataSource.model.fields["First"].editable = true;
grid.dataSource.model.fields["Last"].editable = true;
```

Comment: I like this, its more readable and for reusability. I ended up using the edit function and checking which field was called and if it wasn't the one that was allowed to be edited then i would use closeCell(). But I will be using this from now on and probably change over what I did to use this.